# Button ClientID inside asp:repeater

Tags: javascript, asp.net, repeater

How can I ClientID of button which is inside repeater? When I wrote something like below I get error "btnGetFile doesn't exist". Have any idea??

```
<asp:Repeater id="rep" runat="server">
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnGetFile"
OnClientClick=
'<%# GetOnClientClick((short) Eval("LastAntivirusScanStatus")
, (int) Eval(GP.eRecruiter.Models.Candidates.CandidateCustomFile.PropertyName.Id)
, (string) btnGetFile.ClientID) %>'>
Text
</asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I'm just going to assume that your repeater contol is generating this link 'n' times. You can't use the same ID more than once in a page. It will conflict

Comment: Sure! LinkButton will be generated many times, so I want to get unique ClientID.
I forget to add <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate> tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try :

```
Container.FindControl("btnGetFile").ClientID
```

instead of

```
(string) btnGetFile.ClientID)
```

Comment: Awesome, I forgot about this.  I had even used this format before.  Thanks for posting, it got me unstuck.